# AlarmManager.setAlarmClock() not showing alarm in top right corner on Android Pie

Tags: java, android, kotlin, alarmmanager

I am having an alarm app that sets alarm using following code for devices on Marshmallow and higher:

```
val alarmIntent: PendingIntent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java).let { intent ->
    intent.putExtra(Const.EXTRA_ALARM_ID, alarm.alarmId)
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 
                               alarm.calculateBroadcastId(dayOfWeek),
                               intent, 
                               PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
}

alarmManager.setAlarmClock(
            AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(calendar.timeInMillis, alarmIntent),
            preAlarmIntent)
```

It **works as expected** and shows alarm icon in top right corner (see attachment) on all devices **except** those devices running **Android Pie**.

UPDATE:
Not on all devices running Android Pie, just Samsung (S8) so far.

Is there any additional code that I should add into the pending intent or somewhere in order to show this icon?

Photo of the device running Android Oreo (OS 8.1) and showing alarm icon as expected:
[image]

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue? Google Clock now works property on Android 9 on Samsung. My app still has the same issue as yours.

Comment: hi @YuriyKulikov,
I am still facing the same issue. This is also happening on S10+

Comment: do you have a devices on which this can be reproduced? I have a few ideas what can Samsung be expecting to be put into the intents.

Comment: Hi @YuriyKulikov ,

I am currently using Samsung S10+ which has the same behavior as mentioned in the problem above (related to Samsung S8)

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue on a Galaxy S9 running Pie.  I'm guessing that Samsung did this intentionally to combat problems with background services arising from Android Doze that force some apps to use setAlarmClock(AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo info, PendingIntent operation) to reliably run operations at a fixed interval, even if the phone goes into doze. Now they can do so without showing an annoying alarm icon in the status bar.

Comment: @Glimpse, did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score -2):

In android Pie restrictions are introduced on the apps running in background.

 This is due to new features introduced to improve device power management.

These features are explained in android developer documents in detail.
You can check details in this [Link](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/power).

Hope it helps you !

Comment: I am not sure you got it right, or you are just trying to gain some reputation giving random comments. Read my question once again and pay attention to the details.

Comment: i am also working on some projects and facing the same issue on android pie devices.I hoped it might help you.